# jQuery Mobile Tab - tab selected event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, tabs

By manual http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/tabs/ is unclear if the API has a method to detect when the certain tab has been selected/tapped/clicked.

How to catch this event?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax-content.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Listen to `tabsactivate` event as in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25761165/1771795 API http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Omar the answer is http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

```
   $( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {
                 //some code
    } );
```